# iOS: 4.2 or lower must include ARM6 object code?

Tags: xcode, build, arm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build for armv6 and armv7 architectures with iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5)

I need to build a library and executable that will be installable on both iPhone 3 and iPhone 3gs & later. I guess the iPhone 3 has an arm6 processor and later devices have arm7. However when I try to build for later devices with Build for Active Architectures Only to set No, which would produce an arm6+arm7 binary, the build doesn't complete, because it rejects the library.

Is there a way to get Xcode to build for both arm6 and arm7 without complaints?

Thanks.

Comment: Correction: I unchecked *Build for Active Architectures Only*, & Xcode created two .a files, one for arm6 and arm7. One has to add both of these to a project to do a dual build for both architectures.

Comment: This was asked yesterday. Here's my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5/7490154#7490154