# Not able to debug and run the application in iPhone device using the XCode4

Tags: debugging, ios4, architecture, i386

I trying to install the application into my device, i am getting lots of warning messages and one error.
I am using MAC 10.7 and Xcode 4.1

warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/ThirdParty/ShareKit/Customize UI/SHKCustomShareMenu.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture i386

Error: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1.

can anybody help me 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `SHKCustomShareMenu.m` included in the Build Phases? It should be in Compile Sources.

Answer (score 2):

Please check project setting add the Architectue  "armv6" if missing, because Apple drops the armv6 architecture in iOS5 and refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5).