# Unknown error 0xE8003FFE in iTunes sync (Xcode 4.2, iOS SDK 5.0, iPod 2nd gen iOS 4.2.1)

Tags: ios, sdk, ipod

Probably I missed something, but I can't sync any apps. What I did:

- installed latest xcode+iPhone sdk 4.2
- installed latest iTunes for Windows (10.5.1.4)
- set up deploy target to 3.0 and current SDK to iOS SDK 5.0
- armv7 as base architecture, armv6, armv7 as available
- "build architecture only" unchecked

When I'm syncing with iTunes iPod 2nd gen with iOS 4.2.1 I have unknown error 0xE8003FFE. I tried with and without entitlements enabled. Everything works ok on iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0

Have I missed something with iCloud or some xcode settings?

Answer (score 2):

Did you find this one?
[How to build for armv6 and armv7 architectures with iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5)

I have just had the same issue (same error with armv7, on older devices only).
Adding armv6 finally did do the trick. Follow the link to detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried resetting your iPod? If it doesn't work, try restoring from backup. But before you do I recommend that you backup your iPod.

Comment: hi, yeap, tried : ( reset to default, reinstalling iOS, totally removed everything from ipod (device is just for testing)

Comment: Can you go to Settings>General>Restrictions and see if installing apps is Switched on?

Comment: ok, this fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5