# An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, submit, itunes, distribution

I get the following error in XCode when trying to validate or submit my app to the iTunes app store: "An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store."  The same thing occurs when I try to submit my app directly through the application loader.

I updated to XCode 4.2.1 and reinstalled XCode but the problem still persists.  I submitted an app to the app store a few months ago.  Any advice on how to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: have u made ur application on beta version of ios 5? If yes, you have to either download full version and then re-build your application OR you have to degrade your application for lower version.

Comment: No, the base sdk is iOS 5.0, and it is targeted for 4.0.

Comment: I faced the same problem for iOS beta version, then I found that it should be made for iOS 5.0 full version (if you target to...) else down grade to lower version.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Please see the answer that I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

With the issue you're receiving, it's hard to determine what the root cause is.  Do you have any more context than what you've provided?

Just a theory, but your issue could be that you're targeting 4.0, which requires armv6 architecture support.  If the base SDK is iOS 5.0, you will be using armv7 architecture, which isn't supported for anything prior to 4.3.  Your options would then be to either require 4.3+, or to configure your project to support both architectures.  This is possible, but I did not have a requirement for 4.3 prior, so I just required 4.3+.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5) from SO may help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the title of my app caused the problem.  The title contained characters from a foreign language, and although this caused no problem in iTunes Connect, it apparently chocked XCode.  I simply got rid of these characters in my title, uploaded the application through XCode, and then changed the title again once my binary was uploaded.