# XCode 4.2 and ipod 2nd generation

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-4.2

I'm trying to run my application on my old 2nd generation iPod Touch running iOS 4.2.1 to test it on a non-retina device.

It seems that I have all the certificates and provisioning profiles setup properly, everything works with my iPod Touch 4th generation running iOS 5.0.

However, it neither shows my app on the iPod's screen nor the iPod's installed applications list in Xcode. Without any explicit warning from Xcode.

Could you tell me if I should downgrade to Xcode 3 in order to run and test my application on the old device, or am I doing something wrong? Where should I check?

Thanks!

Comment: I had no trouble in the past installing to an iPod touch 2nd gen from XCode 4.2.  Do you get a green light next to the device in the organizer window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@borrrden is correct that such a device is fine (just tested on one myself, in fact, using Xcode 4.3.x).

My first guess (though it seems odd you wouldn't get an error) is that you are only building for armv7, which at some point became the default in Xcode (don't recall whether this was in 4.2 or 4.3).  You need to make sure that your "valid architectures" and related build settings include both armv6 and armv7 if you are targeting that range of hardware.

Comment: I did update to 4.3.2, but still cannot run my app on ipad 2nd 4.2.1, I can run on ipad 4th 5.0 and ipod 3rd 5.1. Could you please check my configuration http://imgur.com/zXXlg? I've changed ios deployment target to 4.1, my device bacame visible on the list, but still no progress on the issue. My gues is that it can be related to Base SDK an or Architecture, but I've got no other options in this, cannot change it to anything else but 5.1 (it works on ios 5.0 though)

Comment: Yup, that's your problem (or at least *a* problem).  Follow the nice graphical example in the second answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5 (the one with 25 upvotes).

Comment: (The underlying issue is that Apple dropped armv6 from the standard 32 bit architecture list, so you need to manually add it back.)

Comment: (This isn't your fault, btw. It's a fairly arcane issue - most of us don't spend a lot of time thinking about CPU instruction sets.)

Comment: Thanks, I've also needed to remove device capabilities, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7762979/31207