# Distribute ad-hoc app

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, xcode4.3, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to distribute my application to .ipa file which can be added by itunes to device. And i go to developer.apple.com and then:

- Generate Distribution Provisioning Profile, download, install it and use it as "code sign".
- Then install Distribution Certificate
- Go to my Xcode and select product->archive
- Then from Organizer->Archives select my latest copy and select Distribute, select Save For Enterprise or Ad-Hoc and and sign this by my Distribution Provisioning Profile.
- Next i add my mobileprovision file to itunes, add ipa to itunes and try to sync.
- I'm getting an error **0xE8003FFE**

I'm using Xcode **4.3.2**

Comment: Can [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5) helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not great but it is a solution. I restore my iphone to 4.2.1 iOS (from 4.2.1 !!! strange...) and works great. So my only conclusion is that is **NOT** Xcode problem but device/OS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these instructions:

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to General
3. Go to Restrictions(4-digit passcode may be needed)
4. Turn on "Installing Apps"
5. Resync your Device.

Comment: No, after that there is no change.