# Xcode 4.3.2 - Can't add armv6 architecture

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, armv7, armv6

I am working on distributing an app to app store - obviously, for the first time. I want my app to support older versions like iOS 3 and iOS 4. So, I found out that I need to change the architecture value to `armv6 and armv7`. But `Xcode 4.3.2` shows only `armv7`. So, I did a Google search and find out the following two links:

- [armv6 Missing](http://www.idev101.com/code/Xcode/Xcode4/armv6_armv7.html)
- [Warning iPhone apps should include an armv6 architecture even with build config set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4198676/851432)

And I followed the tutorials to do add `armv6` architecture. See the screenshot.

[image: Xcode screenshot - no armv6]

See, only `armv7` is present.

[image: no done button available]

Now, this is my problem. As the above two links says, I selected the other option. Then replaced `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` with `armv6` and `armv7`. **But there is no Done button**. How in the world I make this settings applied without that `Done` button? See the following image from the above links. They have got a `Done` button. But, why not for me?

[image: image from above link with Done button]

Comment: tryied to press the keyboard RETURN button?

Comment: Yes, but it makes the armv6 or armv7 field editable.

Comment: right: then write in the same line both words armv6 and armv7, then RETURN again... PS that's not the only thing to do: in your xxx-info.plist file you have to remove the line for Required device capabilities = armv7

Comment: @meronix I have `Item 0` as `armv6` and `Item 1` as `armv7`. Do I have to remove them all or keep them as it is?

Comment: i removed both and it worked for me

Comment: @meronix Ok. The I will try the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click anywhere outside the popover. It will dismiss the popover and apply your settings. The screenshot with the done button is from an older Xcode version.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! I haven't expected this. Until now, I am using `Esc` key to dismiss the window. Thanks again! +1 and accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

for my experience:

1 try move the setting window for a little distance.

2 three colorful button will show on left top corner of the setting window.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you got the right answer.

But this SOF question also can help you with this architecture related things,now or later.

[How to build for armv6 and armv7 architectures with iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5)