# iPhone xcode 4.5 armv 6 Universal-app

Tags: iphone, xcode, armv7, ios-universal-app, armv6

i have one universal app and now i create one update for iphone 5 
But i can not send my app via apple bc 
Warning : At least one of the following architecturs(s) must be present: armv6
i  added armv 6 armv 7 i389 in target -> architecturs(s) but doesn't work

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488657/how-to-build-for-armv6-and-armv7-architectures-with-ios-5

Comment: You mean you still get that 'at least one of the following' message?

Comment: Yes exacted i adedd armv 6 armv 7 in target but dosent work for upload

Answer (score 1):

Apple dropped support for armv6 with iOS 6 SDK, and XCode 4.5 doesn't support building a binary for armv6 architecture, you must remove it from your target.

Comment: You can hack Xcode 4.5.2 to "enable" armv6 support (apple-llvm-4.1 can generate armv6) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5/12836808#12836808