# Error during upload

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, upload

When i try to upload my app this issues are find during uploading.

.Apple's web service operation was not succesful;

.Unable to authenticate the package: 717652989.itmps

.ERROR ITMS-9000: "this bundle is invalid. When supporting iPhone, the excutable must include support fot the armv6 architecture, unless the UIRequireDeviceCapabilities include the 'armv7'capability". At softwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmpsSoftwareAssetPackage)

Answer (score 0):

As they say - you need to add armv6 architecture to your project.

You can find a lot of questions already asked about that:

[How to add armv6 architecture to Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347802/how-to-add-armv6-architecture-to-xcode-project)

[How to support both armv6 and armv7s for release build in xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619124/how-to-support-both-armv6-and-armv7s-for-release-build-in-xcode-4-5)

Comment: Did you add it to right Target ? Release one ? And both DEBUG / RELEASE configuration?